# Google Tag Manager Custom HTML or Image tag not firing on "all pages"

Tags: google-tag-manager, custom-tag

Currently I am working on a tag implementation in Google Tag Manager which should be pretty straightforward and works just fine for readily available tag templates such as Google Analytics and/or Hotjar.

What I am trying to do is implement a custom HTML tag or Image tag in combination with the "All Pages" trigger. Usually this should have no limitation and the tag should just fire but in this case it won't fire and I am kind of lost on how to proceed.

Tag details:

- It's a image (gif) tag.
- It uses various query parameters and a cache burster solution.
- It's allowed to fire at all times.
- It should fire on every page loaded.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue in Google Tag Manager where a custom tag won't fire on "All pages" but a tag with a template does?

As a side-note: I have used the preview mode in order to identify what tags are fired but haven't seen the tag fire once.

One thing that has noticed me is that the all pages trigger is looking at "gtm.js" and the _event variable is empty when looking at Messages. However, this is also the case for the other tags and they are firing just fine.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Can you share the url of your site? The problem might be in dataLayer declaration using dataLayer = [] assignment after GTM container in page code.

Comment: Unfortunately it's an environment not yet public. However, the dataLayer definition is posted before the initialization of Google Tag Manager and doesn't contain spelling errors.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation was also reviewed on the Google Product Forums and the answer for my problem was posted there.

The dataLayer contained the parameter "gtm.blacklist" which filtered customScripts and customPixels which, logically, will not fire those tags.